# jQuery how to remove or replace text after last

Tags: jquery

Can i remove or replace any texts after lastly apprearing dot(.)

```
ex)OUTsoundfile.123054236.123054236.wav
```

I want to remove .wav or replace .wav with empty string

Can't use `subString` because .wav might not exist in the input text.

Comment: Use `contains` filter to check if .wav exists in the string and then use subString to replace or remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use replace with regexp e.g

```
 'OUTsoundfile.123054236.123054236.wav'.replace(/\.wav/,'');
```

read more about [replace function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Comment: unlike other suggestions, this one is safe to use even there is no '.wav' in the text

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
x.substring(0, x.lastIndexOf("."));
```

<kbd>**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/AVsuj/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

This would be the correct regexp to do it:

```
var myString = "ex)OUTsoundfile.123054236.123054236.wav";
var output = myString.replace(/\.[^.]*$/, '');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/samliew/3UdLH/

Answer (score 0):

Using plain old JavaScript:

```
var filename = "OUTsoundfile.123054236.123054236.wav";
var pieces = filename.split(".");
  // pieces is an array that looks like this:
  // ["OUTsoundfile", "123054236", "123054236", "wav"]

  // Remove the last element from pieces, i.e. "wav"
  // If you want to do anything with this last piece, such as check what the
  // piece you removed was, use the return value of this statement.
pieces.pop();
  // pieces now just looks like this:
  // ["OUTsoundfile", "123054236", "123054236"]

  // Put the string back together
var newFilename = pieces.join(".");
  // newFilename is now this string: "OUTsoundfile.123054236.123054236"
```

Or, without the comments:

```
var filename = "OUTsoundfile.123054236.123054236.wav";
var pieces = filename.split(".");
pieces.pop();
var newFilename = pieces.join(".");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var trimwav = "ex)OUTsoundfile.123054236.123054236.wav";
alert(trimwav.substr(0,x.lastIndexOf(".")));
```